# Uploading multiple files to firbase storage | Unity

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-storage

Hey I'm trying to upload all files located in a folder to firestore storage.
However im quite new to c# and unity.

I have the following code to upload a file located in the folder.

```
       if(Permission.HasUserAuthorizedPermission(Permission.ExternalStorageRead)){
                Debug.Log("Permissions Found");
                var Directory_path = ("SparseSpatialMap/Copia.meta");
                var path = (Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + Directory_path);             
        //Firestore Reference
        storage = FirebaseStorage.DefaultInstance;
        storageReference = storage.GetReferenceFromUrl("gs://houdini-ac884.appspot.com");
   
        StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(path);
        // Create a reference to the file you want to upload
        StorageReference riversRef = storageReference.Child("uploads/newFile.meta");

        // Upload the file to the path "uploads/newFile.meta"
        riversRef.PutStreamAsync(stream.BaseStream)
            .ContinueWith((task) => {
                if (task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled) {
                    Debug.Log(task.Exception.ToString());
                    // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
                }
                else {
                    // Metadata contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
                    StorageMetadata metadata = task.Result;
                    string md5Hash = metadata.Md5Hash;
                    Debug.Log("Finished uploading...");
                    Debug.Log("md5 hash = " + md5Hash);
                }
            });
                    } else {
                            Debug.Log("No Permissions");
                            Permission.RequestUserPermission(Permission.ExternalStorageRead);
                            return;
                    }
```

The file i uploaded with success is located here "  /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/estg.easy.ar/files/SparseSpatialMap/Copia.meta "

I want to upload all files in the /SparseSpatialMap direcory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking for the solution this was how i did it.
got all files via their folder with DirectoryInfo and uploaded each individually using it's the respective name

```
         if (Permission.HasUserAuthorizedPermission(Permission.ExternalStorageRead)){ //Cria ficheiros em branco (Ou por nao ter acesso a um ficheiro que está a ser usado ou por ser Asyncrono)
                Debug.Log("Permissions Found");
                DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(Application.persistentDataPath + "/SparseSpatialMap");
                FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.meta"); //Getting meta files
                string str = "";
                foreach(FileInfo file in Files )
                    {
                str = str + ", " + file.Name;
                var Directory_path = ("SparseSpatialMap/" + file.Name);
                var path = (Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + Directory_path);             
                //Firestore Reference
                storage = FirebaseStorage.DefaultInstance;
                storageReference = storage.GetReferenceFromUrl("gs://houdini-ac884.appspot.com");
                // File located on disk
                string localFile = path.ToString();
                StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(path);
                // Create a reference to the file you want to upload
                StorageReference riversRef = storageReference.Child("uploads/"+ file.Name);
                // Upload the file to the path "uploads/newFile.meta"
                riversRef.PutStreamAsync(stream.BaseStream)
                    .ContinueWith((task) => {
                        if (task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled) {
                            Debug.Log(task.Exception.ToString());
                            // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
                        }
                        else {
                            // Metadata contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
                            StorageMetadata metadata = task.Result;
                            string md5Hash = metadata.Md5Hash;
                            Debug.Log("Finished uploading...");
                            Debug.Log("md5 hash = " + md5Hash);
                        }
                    });
                    }

                    Debug.Log(str);

                    } else {
                            Debug.Log("No Permissions");
                            Permission.RequestUserPermission(Permission.ExternalStorageRead);
                            return;
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you’re looking for is a way to get all file names, or paths. Try importing System.IO if you have already then you can use `Directory.GetFiles(path)` replacing path with the folder directory. Then you should have an array of strings representing each file.